# Unpivot a data-frame that has information of two teams in one row?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have some data that holds information about two opposing teams

```
              home_x           away_x
0                  7               28
1                 11               10
2                 11               20
3                 12               15
4                 12               16
```

I know about .melt(), which returns something like this:

```
            variable  value
0             home_x      7
1             home_x     11
2             home_x     11
3             home_x     12
4             home_x     12
```

So each value is a row here.

There are several attributes for each team.

I want each row to have all the attributes for the respective team( home or away)

The ultimate goals is to have all the attributes of both teams in one row. This would double the number of rows.

```
              home_x           away_x
0                  7               28
```

would be transformed into:

```
             team1_x          team2_x
0                  7               28
0                 28                7
```

Comment: can there also be a `_y`, `_z`..?

Comment: Yes and all would be in a pair home_y, away_y and home_z, away_z

Comment: Thanks, So you would then expect each pair as 2 columns? like `team1_y` and `team2_y` for example?

Comment: yes, they all start with either home or away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**sample df:**

|  | home_x | away_x | home_y | away_y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 7 | 28 | 7 | 20 |
| 1 | 28 | 7 | 28 | 13 |
| 2 | 28 | 7 | 28 | 4 |
| 3 | 7 | 28 | 7 | 58 |
| 4 | 11 | 10 | 11 | 10 |

try:

```
res = pd.DataFrame()
for c in df.columns.str.split("_").str[1].unique():
    p1 = df.filter(regex=f"{c}$")
    c1,c2 =p1.columns
    
    df_map = {c1:c2, c2:c1}
    swap = p1.rename(columns={**df_map})
    res = pd.concat([res,p1.append(swap).sort_index(ignore_index=True)], axis=1)
```

then rename the columns.

```
import re
repl = {'home': 'team1', 'away': 'team2'}
res.columns = [re.sub('|'.join(repl.keys()), lambda x: repl[x.group()], i) for i in res.columns]
```

---

|  | team1_x | team2_x | team1_y | team2_y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 7 | 28 | 7 | 20 |
| 1 | 28 | 7 | 20 | 7 |
| 2 | 28 | 7 | 28 | 13 |
| 3 | 7 | 28 | 13 | 28 |
| 4 | 28 | 7 | 28 | 4 |
| 5 | 7 | 28 | 4 | 28 |
| 6 | 7 | 28 | 7 | 58 |
| 7 | 28 | 7 | 58 | 7 |
| 8 | 11 | 10 | 11 | 10 |
| 9 | 10 | 11 | 10 | 11 |

Comment: Thank you.  I came up with one solution myself. It pretty similar to yours, except that I filter out the ones that start with home and away and than concatenate the two dataframes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach:

You might need to group on the last split of the column names and then group on axis=1, then iterate through the groups and reverse the column order and name them same with the suffix:

```
def myinfo(data):
    c = data.columns.str.split("_").str[-1]
    f = lambda x: pd.DataFrame.set_axis(x, ["team1","team2"],axis=1)
    l = [pd.concat([*map(f , (v,v.iloc[:,::-1]))]).add_suffix(f"_{k}")
         for k,v in data.groupby(c,axis=1)]
    return pd.concat(l,axis=1).sort_index()
```

---

```
print(myinfo(df))

   team1_x  team2_x
0        7       28
0       28        7
1       11       10
1       10       11
2       11       20
2       20       11
3       12       15
3       15       12
4       12       16
4       16       12
```